# Having issues appending tab on cell click within observeEvent function in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This is the minimum reproducible example needed to help:

```
ui.R

library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  title = 'DataTables Information',
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Cars overview",
                             h1("Cars overview"),
                             div("Click any cell"),
                             br(),
                             DT::dataTableOutput("x4")
                    )
        )
)
```

Server script:

```
server.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, selection = 'single')
  }, server = TRUE) 



  observeEvent(input$x4_cells_clicked, {
    print("Trigger")
    value <- x4_cells_clicked$value
    details <- mtcars %>%
        filter(mpg == value)
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(
                  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(details), server = TRUE)

              )
    )
    # Focus on newly created tab
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected = "Car details")

  })

})
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to trigger an event through a cell click on the mtcars dataframe. I want to append a tab upon a click and filter the dataframe that is produced by the value within the cell that is clicked. I know in this case I am only accounting for a click on the mpg column but I just need to see how a click on a cell is registered through observeEvent and how to use the value of the cell clicked to filter the dataframe that is produced in the new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'DataTables Information',
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Cars overview",
                       h1("Cars overview"),
                       div("Click any cell"),
                       br(),
                       DTOutput("x4")
              )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$x4 = renderDT({
    datatable(mtcars, selection = 'single')
  }, server = TRUE) 

  observeEvent(input$x4_cell_clicked, {
    cell <- input$x4_cell_clicked
    if(length(cell)){
      details <- mtcars[mtcars[[cell$col]]==cell$value,]
      appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(
                  "Cars details",
                  renderDT(datatable(details), server = TRUE)
                ), 
                select = TRUE # Focus on newly created tab
      )
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```